# Problems with Getting Remote Contents using Google App Engine

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine

Here is the client side code. It is running insdide a Google Gadgets

```
  var params = {};
  params[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.CONTENT_TYPE] = gadgets.io.ContentType.JSON;
  var url = "http://invplatformtest.appspot.com/getrecent/";
  gadgets.io.makeRequest(url, response, params);
```

The response function is:

```
function response(obj)
  {
  var r = obj.data;
  alert(r['name']);
  }
```

while on the server end, the python code sending the JSON is:

```
class GetRecent(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write({'name':'geocities'}) #i know this is where the problem is so how do i encode json in GAE?
```

which is just supposed to send back a Json encoded string
but when i run this, the javascript throws the following error:

```
r is null
   alert(r['name']);
```

If i were recieving just TEXT contents and my server send TEXT everything works fine. I only get this problem when am trying to send JSON. Where exactly is the problem? Am i encoding the JSON the wrong way on AppEngine? I tried using the JSON library but it looks as if this is not supported.

Where is the problem exactly? :(

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not encoding JSON at all - you're just passing a Python dictionary to self.request.out.write, and expecting it to know what to do with it. Import `django.utils.simplejson`, and call `simplejson.dumps()` on the dictionary to convert it to JSON.

Comment: true...tried pythons native json library but apparently that did not work...thanks for pointing out django's simplejson